# Campo de pesquisa e paginação

Tags: php, sql

Tenho como objetivo a realização de um campo de pesquisa, como tambéma paginação, ambos funcionavam até que realizei um popup que tinha como finalidade apresentar os dados de cada cliente que se encontravam inseridos em outras tabelas, através da realização de JOINS fui capaz de realizar tal tarefa, mas desde então que  ao realizar uma pesquisa nenhuma alteração é feita, apresenta que existe mais que uma página mas no entanto quando vou clicar na segunda página apresenta exatamente o mesmo que a primeira e os dados conseguem ser inseridos com sucesso mas no entanto não são apresentados , no entanto sempre que apago o JOIN realizado tudo volta ao normal.

```html
    
<?php header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<?php
 if (isset($_REQUEST['pesquisa']) && $_REQUEST['pesquisa']!='') {
  $pesq1=$_REQUEST['pesquisa']; 
  $pesq=$_REQUEST['pesquisa']; 
  $pesq='%'.$pesq1.'%';
 }else 
  $pesq='';
 
 $tp=10;
 if (isset($_REQUEST['pag'])) $np=$_REQUEST['pag']; else $np=1;
 
 $ini=($np-1)*$tp; //registo inicial a ser mostrado
 $sql="select * from Terceiros where  1=1"; 
 if ($pesq !='') 
  $sql.=" and upper(Numero) like upper('$pesq')";
 $sql.=" order by Numero";
 $res=$lig->query($sql);
 $nr=$res->num_rows;
 $qp=$nr/$tp+1;
 mysql_free_result($res);
 ?>
  
 <form align="center" method="POST" action="index.php?cmd=lister">
  Pesquisar Terceiros: <input type="text" name="pesquisa" value="<?php echo $pesq1; ?>">
  <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
 </form>
 <p align="center">
 
<?php
 if ($pesq !='')
  echo "<center><a style='border-style: solid; padding:4px; border-width: thin;' href=index.php?cmd=lister>Listar todos os terceiros </a></center>";
?>

<?php
 $sql="select  * from Terceiros where 1=1 ";
 if ($pesq !='')
  $sql.=" and upper(Numero) like upper('$pesq') ";
 $sql.=" ORDER BY Numero limit $ini, $tp";
 $res=$lig->query($sql);

?>

<div class="container" align="center" >
 <p align="center">
 </div>
 <br><br>
 
 
<?php 
 if ($filtro !='')
  echo "<center><a style='border-style: solid; padding:4px; border-width: thin;' href=index.php?cmd=lister>Listar os terceiros </a></center>";
?>    
              
<div class="container">
  <h1 align="center">Listar Terceiros</h1> <br><br>      
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
 <tr>
      <tr>
   <th colspan=2>
    <a href="index.php?cmd=addter">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Adicionar Terceiro</button>
    </a>
   </th>
  </tr> 
       <th>Numero</th>
        <th>Cliente</th>
  <th>Fornecedor</th>
  <th>NIF</th>
  <th>Nome</th>
  <th>IdSiliamb</th>
  <th>Tipo</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT Terceiros.*, Email, Telefone, Telemovel, TipoC, Morada, Localidade, CodPostal from Terceiros, Contactos_Terceiro, Morada_Terceiro ";
$sql.="WHERE Contactos_Terceiro.CodCon = Terceiros.CodCon and Morada_Terceiro.Numero = Terceiros.Numero  ";
$res=$lig->query($sql);         
while ($lin=$res->fetch_array()){ ?> 
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo$lin[Numero]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo$lin[Cliente]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[Fornecedor]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[NIF]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[Nome]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[Idsiliamb]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[Tipo]; ?></td>      
                                
        <td><a href=index.php?cmd=editer&Numero=<?php echo$lin[Numero];?> title="Editar"><img src='Imagens/edit.png' width="20" height = "20" ></a></td>
  <td><a href=index.php?cmd=delter&Numero=<?php echo$lin[Numero];?> title="Apagar" onclick="return confirm('Tem a certeza que deseja apagar este registo?');" ><img src='Imagens/delete.png' width="20" height = "20" ></a></td>
  <td><td><button data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#<?php echo$lin[Numero];?>" title="Visualizar" class="btn btn-default openBtn"><img src='Imagens/eye.png' width="20" height = "20" ><button></td></td>
      </tr> 
                                                                    <!-- Inicio do PopUp -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="<?php echo $lin['Numero']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">

         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo $lin['Nome']; ?></h4>
           </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
               <div class="table-responsive">
                                                <div class="divTable blueTable">
                                                <div class="divTableHeading">
                                                <div class="divTableRow">
                                                    <div class="divTableHead">Telefone</div>
                                                    <div class="divTableHead">Telemovel</div>
                                                    <div class="divTableHead">Email</div>
                                                    <div class="divTableHead">Tipo</div>
                                                    <div class="divTableHead">Morada</div>
                                                    <div class="divTableHead">Localidade</div>
                                                    <div class="divTableHead">Codigo Postal</div>

                                                </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="divTableBody">
                                                <div class="divTableRow">
                                                    <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $lin['Telefone']; ?></div>
                                                    <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $lin['Telemovel']; ?></div>
                                                    <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $lin['Email']; ?></div>
                                                    <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $lin['TipoC']; ?></div>
                                                    <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $lin['Morada']; ?></div>
                                                    <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $lin['Localidade']; ?></div>
                                                    <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $lin['CodPostal']; ?></div>
                                                </div>
                                                </div>
                                                </div>

              </div>
         </div>
         </div>
            </div>
                                         <!-- Fim do PopUp -->
        
        
<?php } ?>

    </tbody>
  </table>  
</div> 
<p align=center>
<?php for ($i=1; $i<$qp; $i++)
  echo "<a href=index.php?cmd=lister&pag=$i&pesquisa=$pesq1>&nbsp$i&nbsp</a>";
?>
</p>
```

```html
<!-- Aqui encontra-se o JOIN que mencionei anteriormente e o que se encontra igualmente no trecho de código acima. -->



<?php
$sql = "SELECT Terceiros.*, Email, Telefone, Telemovel, TipoC, Morada, Localidade, CodPostal from Terceiros, Contactos_Terceiro, Morada_Terceiro ";
$sql.="WHERE Contactos_Terceiro.CodCon = Terceiros.CodCon and Morada_Terceiro.Numero = Terceiros.Numero  ";
$res=$lig->query($sql); 

<?
```

Comment: *" a pesquisa e a paginação deixaram de funcionar "* precisa explicar melhor isso para podermos ajudar, o que parou de funcionar? dá erro, não retorna valor?

Comment: Lamento não ter sido explicita, ao realizar a pesquisa nenhuma alteração é feita, apresenta que existe mais que uma página mas no entanto quando vou clicar na segunda página apresenta exatamente o mesmo que a primeira e os dados conseguem ser inseridos com sucesso mas no entanto não são apresentados

Comment: *" através da realização de JOINS fui capaz de realizar tal tarefa"* se fez alguma alteração ela deve também ser usada para recuparar os resultados, senão eles podem ser diferentes... os selects que vi no seu código estão diferentes, não deveriam ser iguais?

Comment: Quer dizer, que o select que fiz para o popup, deveria ser o mesmo para a paginação e pesquisa?

Comment: pelo menos a parte do `from`, `where` e `order by` deveriam ser iguais... não consegui ver bem no seu codigo porque não está completo, mas imagina que fez uma consulta que retorna por exemplo 100 resultados, e quer paginar a cada 50, então tem duas páginas.. .mas se fizer uma consulta diferente depois pode mudar o resultado do total de paginas e do que deve aparecer em cada página

Comment: Poderia apresentar onde precisava de realizar a alteração por favor? Porque assim dito não estou a conseguir visualizar